# Playing an embedded Youtube video directly in the Youtube app

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

I am using a very low speced smart-phone and heavy sites like Khan Academy are very difficult to load.

When ever I watch a video on their site my phone slow down and frequently crashes.

*So, is there a way to directly play the embedded Youtube video in the app.*

I want to do this because, that page could be locked away for a while, and I can concentrate on the lectures.

And can this be done without compromising the sites features, like the one that keeps track of "which and how much videos one has seen", so I could get my "energy points" and keep track of my performance. In other words, KA must know what videos I have watched.